# ionic-react how to animate with <CreateAnimation> on component re render?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, animation, ionic-react

I am using below code to animate my slider menu as there is no proper example of ionic menu controller for react.

```
<CreateAnimation
            play={isLoaded}
            duration={500}
            fromTo={[
                { property: 'transform', fromValue: animateFrom, toValue: animateTo }
            ]}>


            ...my slider UI

</CreateAnimation>
```

The problem is, it's working fine for first time. but after that It doesn't even after my component re renders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/start

**sidemenu** - A starting project with a side menu with navigation in the content area

```
Starters for @ionic/react (--type=react)

name         | description
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
blank        | A blank starter project
list         | A starting project with a list
my-first-app | An example application that builds a camera with gallery
sidemenu     | A starting project with a side menu with navigation in the content area
tabs         | A starting project with a simple tabbed interface
conference   | A kitchen-sink application that shows off all Ionic has to offer
```